# Form_validation not running if data

Tags: mysql, validation, forms, codeigniter

I have edited the below code to keep it upto date with changes I have made. I have managed to get it saving **BUT** I still cannot get the '**success**' message to display when the redirect is completed.  Also if there is an **incorrect** error how can I make the entered data save?

**Controller**

```
class Addsale extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}
function index() {
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('admin/home');
    }
    // set data
    $data['title'] = "Add Sale";
    $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bedrooms', 'Bedrooms', 'trim|is_natural|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bathrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('condition', 'Condition', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {

    $data = array(  
        'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE),
        'bedrooms' => $this->input->post('bedrooms', TRUE),
        'bathrooms' => $this->input->post('bathrooms', TRUE),
        'condition' => $this->input->post('condition', TRUE),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price', TRUE)
        );

        $this->sales_model->addSale($data);

        redirect('admin/addsale' , $data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page Saved');

    }else{
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/addsale', NULL, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }

}


    }
```

**View**

```
<?php
//Setting form attributes
$formAddSale = array('id' => 'addSale', 'name' => 'addSale');
$saleName = array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name'); 
$saleLocation = array('id' => 'location', 'name' => 'location');
$saleBedrooms = array('id' => 'bedrooms','name' => 'bedrooms');
$saleBathrooms = array('id' => 'bathrooms','name' => 'bathrooms'); 
$saleCondition = array('id' => 'condition','name' => 'condition');
$saleDescription = array('id' => 'description','name' => 'description');
$salePrice = array('id' => 'price','name' => 'price');
?>

<section id = "validation"><?php print $this->session->flashdata('success');?> </section>
<section id = "validation"><?php echo validation_errors();?></section>

<?php
echo form_open('admin/addsale/', $formAddSale); 
echo form_fieldset();
echo form_label('Name:', 'name');
echo form_input($saleName);
echo form_label ('Location', 'location');
echo form_input($saleLocation);
echo form_label ('Bedrooms', 'bedrooms');
echo form_input($saleBedrooms);
echo form_label ('Bathrooms', 'bathrooms');
echo form_input($saleBathrooms);
echo form_label ('Condition', 'condition');
echo form_input($saleCondition);
echo form_label ('Price', 'price');
echo form_input($salePrice);
echo form_label ('Description', 'description');
echo form_textarea($saleDescription);
echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
echo form_fieldset_close();
echo form_close();
?>
```

**Model**

```
function addSale($data) {

$this->db->insert('sales', $data);
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like there is one too many "=" in this line:

```
 if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks that was not the issue = I did not pass an array $data

Answer (score 3):

You're using set_message to display the "completed" message? If so, this won't display since you're doing a redirect just before it.

Try setting a message in flashdata just before the redirect, like so:

> $this->session->set_flashdata('success',
>   'Page Saved');

and then print it out in your view:

> print $this->session->flashdata('success')